# Normalizing variables with logarithmic shape

Tags: normalization, distribution, logarithmic

A simple model with two variables [A,B] to train, let's say, a logistic regression or any other classification model:

- A: Flat distribution from 0 to 100.
- B: A logarithmic distribution from 0
  to a few thousands.

What would be the proper way to normalize this? Should I make B flat before? Do I put a limit before the max in B and consider all points above like the max?

I read you carefully. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is normalization? and its formula? flat distribution?

Comment: It is a process ending with A and B having the same difference between max and min value so the models do not priorize one variable over the other.